# Create a new variable which is the fold change of one row over another row and do this for multiple variables

Tags: r, dplyr, slice, tidyverse

I have samples that were run and generated data on 8 variables. Each sample has a "NIL" run, and 3 other 'versions' of the same sample (sometimes 4 or 5). What I need is, to create 8 new variables, which would be the fold change of each version of a sample vs the NIL of that sample.

To run this for all variables, I know I need to use something like mutate_at(.funs=funs(FUNCTION HERE), .vars=var1:var8). However, I cannot figure out what function to use.

```
x<-c(50,25,10,5)
y<-c(100,50,25,10)
z<-c(50,25,10,5)

sample<-c("a","a","a","a") 
sample_type<-c("a_bcg","a_esf","a_hiv","a_nil")
## sample_type column is the one which would serve as a reference for 
## me of how these "a"s are different from each other but for 
## calculation purposes we can just group by sample  
test<-as.tibble(cbind(x,y,z,sample))
test<-test%>%
  modify_at(c(1,2,3),as.numeric)

test%>%
  group_by(sample)%>% ## since there'd be more groups 
  mutate_at(.funs = funs(./slice(n)),.vars = (1:3))
```

This fails 
    Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
      Evaluation error: no applicable method for 'slice_' applied to an 
    object of class "c('double', 'numeric')".

I need to create a function that takes the value of every row of a column and divides it with a particular row (in that sub group) - and that row has a "nil" in it so I could make it such that the nil sample could either always be the first or the last in the group.

```
The expected would look like this 

x     y     z     sample   x_1   y_1   z_1
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 50    100   50    a         10  10      10
2 25    50    25    b          5   5       5
3 10    25    10    c          2   2.5     2
4 5     10    5     nil        1   1       1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a reference `ref` column in your data which indicates the "nil" row to divide with. Your expected result would then be given by:

```
library(tidyverse)

x <- c(50,25,10,5)
y <- c(100,50,25,10)
z <- c(50,25,10,5)

sample <- c("a","a","a","a") 
sample_type <- c("a_bcg","a_esf","a_hiv","a_nil")
## sample_type column is the one which would serve as a reference for 
## me of how these "a"s are different from each other but for 
## calculation purposes we can just group by sample  

ref <- c(0, 0, 0, 1)
test <- as.tibble(cbind(x,y,z,sample, ref))
test <- test%>%
          modify_at(c(1,2,3),as.numeric)

test%>%
  group_by(sample)%>% ## since there'd be more groups 
  mutate_at(.funs = funs( `1` = . / .[ref == 1]), .vars = (1:3))
```

I've kept your code as close as possible to how you posted it.

Comment: That's amazing. I figured a slightly different version which ordered the ref such that the 1 is always the first row in the group and and use " .[1] ". But your solution is so much more flexible.